# Сочинительный и подчинительный союзы в начале предложения не разделяются запятой. Только ли в начале?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, сложное-предложение

Известные правила:

- > <...> (в начале предложения, после точки) ...как правило, после союза ***и***
  > запятая не ставится: ***И когда** Левинсон, выполнив все будничные дела,
  > отдал наконец приказ выступать, — в отряде наступило такое ликование,
  > точно с этим приказом на самом деле кончались всякие мытарства* (Ф.); ***И
  > хотя** погода значительно улучшилась, опасность засухи не миновала; **И
  > вместо того чтобы** свернуть направо, по ошибке поехали прямо...* [Розенталь];
- > В начале предложения не разделяются запятой сочинительный и
  > подчинительный союзы, а также подчинительный союз и союзное слово:
  > *Денис помер. **И когда** я уезжал, старуха его вынесла мне гуся...*
  > (Пришв.); *И прости, и уже навсегда, навеки... **Потому что где же** они
  > теперь могут встретиться?* (Бун.) [Лопатин].

Однако только ли после точки не ставится запятая после союза *и*? Мне кажется логичным, что и в начале второго (третьего и т. д.) простого предложения в ССП запятая также может не стоять, **как полагаете?**

Примеры такой пунктуации из Нацкорпуса (специально выбрал такие, в которых нет коррелята "то"):

- > Но Таня удивительно легко расправилась с Василисиными принципами,
  > сказавши, что в такую даль она ни за что не поедет, поскольку и
  > сама-то она точно не знает, с чего это ей взбрело в голову крестить
  > ребёнка, и если уж возникают такие трудности, она готова и отказаться
  > от этой блажи (Улицкая);
- > Свет был какой-то синий и неживой, и если бы не Луна, которую можно
  > было увидеть, сильно наклонившись с кровати вправо, было бы совсем
  > жутко (Пелевин);
- > Всё же дети рождаются не с велосипедными колёсами, а по-прежнему с
  > ручками, ножками, и если такого голландского младенца вовремя увезти в
  > другую страну, из него вырастет нормальный пешеход (Гранин);
- > Хозяйка дала мне разложить вилки, и когда они вдвоём с Володей
  > удалились на кухню, я услышала её заговорщицкий шёпот: "Немедленно
  > женись, говорю тебе" (Спивакова);
- > И в этой точке открывалось, что любая педагогика есть бред и холодный
  > рационализм, и когда начинается педагогика, отступает природное
  > чувство, глубокое, животное чувство любви к детёнышу… (Улицкая).

Comment: Просто многие не хотят ставить запятую из-за того, что нет паузы. Нет тайных причин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Русская пунктуация основана **на трех принципах** – семантическом, грамматическом и интонационном. Первый принцип – это содержание, а два других – форма.  Все понятно:  для конкретного содержания мы подбираем оптимальную форму как в устной, так и в письменной речи.

Но как-то туда попал еще и **формальный принцип** (совершенно, как мне кажется, незаконно). Сами по себе формальные правила могут быть полезными – они помогают пользователям в ряде случаев избегать сложного грамматического анализа. Но если его возводить в абсолют, то тогда  он **становится препятствием** для проявления основных принципов пунктуации – мешает понять содержание и грамматику, нарушает интонационную форму.

2. Речь пойдет о формальном правиле  **«возможности перестановки  придаточного предложения»:** если можно переставить, то придаточное обособляется запятыми. Польза от такого правила видится одна: так можно определить  предложения с двойными союзами вида «если то». Тогда мы не делим СПП на части, а воспринимаем его как единую синтаксическую единицу.

Но ведь двойные союзы и так можно определить, то есть чисто визуально.  Правило актуально на этапе обучения, но его сделали обязательным даже в тех случаях, когда при перестановке **семантика предложения нарушается.**

3. Сейчас общество представляется более развитым и подготовленным, чтобы обойтись без этого формализма.  В сложном предложении из нескольких предикативных основ важно разобраться **в его главной структуре**, то есть во взаимном отношении входящих в его состав конструкций. И вот такая **«расчлененка» СПП** мешает этому, не позволяет  выявить основные «блоки», правильно поставить знаки между ними. **Но правило действует!** Последователи формализма видят в нем главный аргумент  для своих решений, а синтаксический анализ их мало интересует (для этого в грамматике надо разбираться).
4. И вот общество **голосует против формального правила** практикой письма. Возможно, писатели тоже небольшие знатоки грамматических форм, но у них есть чувство языка, которое помогает им выбрать  правильный вариант. И тогда они не ставят запятую после сочинительных союзов, не обособляют придаточное, если не считают это необходимым. Можно еще вспомнить, что обособление всегда  связано со **вставочной интонацией**, которой, разумеется, там нет.

**ВЫВОД.** Поэтому я тоже, как и автор вопроса,  считаю, что и в середине предложения запятая после союза И  может не стоять.  А приведенные примеры из Нацкорпуса подтверждают это.