# Все ли запятые поставлены в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

***Всех свидетелей прошу собраться у входа, но пока не позову не заходить*** (Б. Акунин, 2022 г.)

Почему автор не обособил придаточное предложение с союзом ПОКА? Это ошибка, авторское решение? Можно как-то объяснить отсутствие обособления?

Книга «серьезная», автор хорошо известен, как-то не очень верится, что две запятые случайно пропущены.

Comment: Хоть бы уже вторую поставил. Честно говоря, из-за отсутствия запятых сразу и прочитать не получалось, даже показалось, что слова неправильно читаю. Могли попутать из-за того, что "прошу" и "не позову" кажутся однородными и находящимися в одном простом предложении.

Comment: Да, читается невнятно. Но с обособлением двумя запятыми будет тоже некрасиво. А как написать красивый и понятный вариант? Есть предложения?

Comment: С одной запятой. Это правило часто нарушают. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/469864

Comment: Всех свидетелей прошу собраться у входа, но  не заходить, пока не позову  (уж лучше так написать). Я считала, что здесь однородные сказуемые. Он же ПРОСИТ собраться, но не заходить.  А если это два предложения, то вторая часть выглядит как требование.

Comment: Хороший пример. Вот это одна из актуальных проблем пунктуации. Помните мои примеры про покупку яблок? Так вот здесь такое же. Для отделения (требования) лучше использовать более сильный знак. Найти бы информацию об этом... Вся надежда на Розенталя.

Comment: @oleedd "но" — это противительный союз, в моём вопросе про него ничего не было. В примерах речь идёт о выпуске запятой после сочинительных союзов, а также после союза 'и'.

Comment: @Nektoid Без разницы. Правило то же (запятая на стыке союзов).

Comment: @oleedd нет, не "без разницы". Про союз 'но' в правиле сказано отдельно: "3) после союза *но* запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет". Таким образом, никакого нарушения правила нет, и ссылка на мой вопрос, где говорится о случаях нарушения, не годится.

Comment: @Nektoid После И в начале предложения тоже ставится, если есть пауза. А после НО разрешается не ставить только в начале предложения. Так что нарушение есть.

Comment: @oleedd нарушения правил нет, потому что указанное вами — и есть правило.

Comment: @Nektoid Вы читать умеете? Розенталь: Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (**в начале предложения, после точки**) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит от значения союза: 3) после союза *но* запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет. А здесь не начало предложения, союз НО не после точки.

Comment: @Sharon + ещё парочка ляпов корректора... Или тоже, скажете, всё объяснимо? :) **1** *Тема нашего урока не «идеальный детектив», а теплокровные и живородящие персонажи.* — перед "не" должно быть тире, потому что при противопоставлении сказуемое с отрицанием требует постановки тире; **2** *«Эх, доктор, – мечтательно ответил объект исследования. – А вы сами попробуйте. За уши не оттащишь!».* — точка после закр. кавычки не нужна, если в кавычках целое предложение и в конце воскл. знак.

Comment: @Nektoid (1) Откуда вы взяли правило, что "при противопоставлении сказуемое с отрицанием требует постановки тире". Ничего такого оно не требует, постановка знака факультативная и зависит от логических ударений. "Тема нашего урока не «идеАльный детектив», а теплокровные и живородящие персонАжи. Здесь ударением выделено сказуемое, а на подлежащее ударение не падает. Соответственно, паузы и тире нет.  Но узнав, что Нарумов не инженер, а конногвардеец, она сожалела, что высказала свою тайну ветреному Томскому. (2) Ну точку да, корректор пропустил, но это мелочи. Для первого издания простительно.

Comment: @Nektoid  Кстати, вы с ультрамарином разобрались, не осталось вопросов? А вот автор ответ не принимает, вероятно, ему не все понятно. Сказано, что используются две формы, а какая из них более правильная и почему?  Возможно, один из вариантов разговорный, тогда его "правильным" не всегда можно назвать. А ведь вопрос был "как правильно", а не "как говорят".

Comment: @Sharon автор принял мой ответ, но ответ со ссылкой на БТС очевидно верный, а мой таковым не был, поэтому я попросил модератора его удалить.

Comment: @Sharon про сказуемое с отрицанием: Лопатин, §15.3: "[Тире не ставится:] Если при сказуемом-существительном имеется отрицание: Пейзаж не довесок к прозе и не украшение (Пауст.); Россия не Петербург, она огромная (Пришв.); Старость не радость  (посл.). Однако при противопоставлении сказуемое с отрицанием требует постановки тире (не… а): И в то же время замечал, что он — не господин в своем доме, а лишь составная часть его (М. Г.) (ср. без противопоставления: Он не господин в своем доме )". Что касается точки не на месте после кавычки, то в книге это неоднократная ошибка.

Comment: Если ответить кратко, то это так. Вы поменьше читайте Лопатина, а побольше – классику, вот и будет вам счастье. Его правила – это махровый формализм, он хочет из нас пишущих роботов сделать. В пунктуации однозначные решения никак нельзя приветствовать, об этом говорит Розенталь. Его справочник – руководство для школьников. Хорошо еще, что есть практика письма, которая будет противостоять этим чиновникам, у которых языковой слух полностью отсутствует. Вот Розенталь не стал регламентировать эту тему, так как она требует более высокого уровня понимания, а тогда об этом еще рано было говорить.

Comment: @Sharon во времена Розенталя многие моменты не сложились на практике, вот он и осторожничал. Лопатин же фиксировал чаще всего сложившуюся практику, не забывая о логике (которая не равно формализм).
Что мне читать и на кого ориентироваться — я разберусь, спасибо за заботу.

Comment: Не обижайтесь, это же шутка, я рассчитывала на ваше чувство юмора. Помните, у Булгакова: "и никогда не читайте утренних газет".  Но всё дело в том, то практика в данном случае скорее противоречит правилам ПАС. Я приведу примеры с разными формами написания.  Решение зависит от того, то мы хотим выделить, подлежащее или сказуемое. (1)  ПисАтельство –  НЕ ремесло и НЕ занятие. Писательство – призвание. Наша задАча – НЕ отразить атаку врага, А уничтожить противника.

Comment: (2) Дятел НЕ ТОЛЬКО плотник, НО И отличный верхолаз. Душа Печорина НЕ каменистая почва, НО засохшая от зноя земля. Стихи НЕ каприз и НЕ шалость. Стихи не сдаются на милость. Ему без стихов не дышалось, Ему без стихов не любилось. Так то извините меня еще раз. Видите, специально подбираю для вас лирические стихи.

Comment: @Sharon правило Лопатина касается только последовательности "не... а...", оно не упоминает "не... но...". В Ваших же примерах тире — именно интонационный знак, знак усиления членения, против чего ни Розенталь, ни Лопатин, кажется, не возражают.

Comment: «Душа Печорина НЕ каменистая почва, А засохшая от зноя земля». А здесь вы поставите  тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня тут возникла идея, что автор решил 'пока не позову' считать эдаким авторским наречным выражением. Не заходить (как?) пока не позову.

UPD: начал читать книгу, за несколько страниц наткнулся на две пунктуационные ошибки:

- > Когда очень многим людям становится интересно то же, что раньше было
  > интересно только тебе, это главная награда для писателя-беллетриста. *[нет тире перед **это**];*
- > (Я тогда еще не знал, что всякая книга начинается со сбора
  > материалов). *[точка должна стоять перед скобкой, потому что в скобках
  > целое предложение; эта ошибка вообще по всему тексту]*.

Comment: В принципе идея неплохая, я тоже об этом думала.  У нас нераспространенное придаточное предложение, которое по значению равно одной падежной форме "без вызова":  Всех свидетелей прошу собраться у входа, но без вызова не заходить.  Сказуемое: прошу собраться, но не заходить. У Розенталя есть тема устойчивых выражений на основе придаточных предложений, но там перечислена их тематика. Я думаю, что автор как бы расширил ее.  Ведь задача пунктуации – это  оформить содержание оптимальным образом, не усложняя конструкцию и не перегружая ее знаками препинания. Вероятно, цель была именно такая.

Comment: Либо же корректор просто профукала запятую, а мы тут городим огород :)

Comment: Две запятые не пропустишь, к тому  они там плохо смотрятся.  А при постановке одной запятой меняется конструкция. А что вас не устраивает в объяснении?

Comment: Запятая пропущена одна, потому что после "но", по Розенталю, она факультативна (после союза *но* запятая ставится при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет [§ 36]). А пунктуационные ошибки в книге ещё имеются, что дискредитирует корректора. Я дополнил ими ответ.

Comment: Здесь союз НО относится ко второму однородному сказуемому.

Comment: "Когда очень многим людям становится интересно то же, что раньше было интересно только тебе, это главная награда для писателя-беллетриста. [нет тире перед это];"  А вы уверены, что там ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО должно быть  тире? "Когда идет дождь, это не очень приятно". Здесь тоже нужно тире?

Comment: @Sharon на мой взгляд, в предложении "Когда идет дождь, это не очень приятно" требуется тире. Тире перед *это* не ставится в двух случаях: если *это* — указательное местоимение (не наш случай) и если *это* — указательное слово на границе двух предложений (похоже на наш случай, но мне кажется, что и тут, и у Акунина  *это* — всё же связка).

Comment: @Sharon честно говоря, *это* мне вообще кажется тут неуместным. Ну не указывает оно на то, что стоит за словом "когда". Ощущение, что говорится про нечто, что неприятно в период дождя, а не про сам дождь. "Когда солнечно, я люблю гулять. Когда идёт дождь, это [т. е. гулять] не очень приятно". "Когда я вышел из дома, это было ошибкой" — ну не звучит, какой-то анаколуф. "Когда я вышел из дома, то понял, что это была ошибка" — вот так надо. Не сочетается *это* с *когда*. Думаю, где-то в справочниках по стилистике это оговорено.

Comment: Связки бывают в простом предложении между подлежащим и сказуемым, а в общем случае "это"  называют анафорическим элементом, указывающим назад, на первую часть предложения.    Ну вот пример из реального текста: Говорят, если в день свадьбы идет дождь, это счастливая примета.  Местоимение указывает на содержание всего придаточного предложения.  Не делается пауза, вот и тире не ставится.

Comment: @Sharon Первый раз слышу этот термин — анафорический элемент :) Век живи, как говорится, дураком помрёшь. Хорошо, значит, я неправ был, в первом примере ошибки корректора нет.

Comment: А про катафорический элемент слышали (обычай мой таков...),  он отсылает нас вперед, вниз, ко второй части. Греческие приставки. А по поводу точки после скобок  я с Акуниным согласна – никто не может мне объяснить, почему ее ставят внутри скобок. Точка – символический, замыкающий знак. Я, конечно, слушаюсь, ставлю где надо, а Акунин  не хочет делать то, что непонятно.

Comment: @Sharon, получается, что то же самое *это* может быть катафорическим элементом, если отсылает не назад, а вперёд: "**Это** было интересно — побывать на премьере"?

Comment: Ну да, это касается и слова "так", например: Он сказал так: приеду завтра. Приеду завтра — так он сказал. Даже знаки ставим разные.  А некоторые пользователи  ориентируются на конкретное слово "так", в то время как надо учитывать, где оно расположено.  Так что не зря вы познакомились с новыми словами. Греческая приставка  встречается в заимствованных словах, например: katalogos «список, перечень» — сложение kata «внизу» и logos «слово..

Comment: Кстати, вы не хотите определиться с вашим решением: здесь авторская пунктуация или ошибка корректора.?Что скажете о предложенной вами  первоначальной версии?

Comment: Не хочу, потому что оба варианта считаю равновозможными :)

Comment: Жаль... Может, добавите в пользу первой вашей  (и моей тоже) версии хотя бы  десять процентов?   :)

Comment: Хорошо, +10% к первому варианту, + 10% ко второму, итого 120%, и кто чё мне сделает, гуманитарию :))

Comment: Да уж, такую задачку мне не решить. Мне кажется, что ничего не изменилось, но я не уверена...  Ну ладно, считайте, что вопрос ваш.

Comment: @Sharon Такая структура с "это" не очень правильна, там скрытые проблемы. "Это" соотносится со словом "то": *То, что идёт дождь, — [это] не очень приятно.* А с "когда" структура нарушается: *То, когда идёт дождь, — это не очень приятно.* Через слово "это" определяется слово/словосочетание, а здесь нет такого. Не следует через слово "это" определять условие. Это не грамотная речь. Точка внутри скобок, потому что в таком случае скобки не являются частью предложения, предложение начинается не со скобки, а после неё. В скобки можно поставить и несколько предложений.

Comment: @oleedd через "это" всё же можно определять условие, но только если условие стоит после, а не перед. Сравните: "Когда идёт дождь, это плохо" — совершенно не звучит. А так: "Плохо — это когда идёт дождь"? Совсем другое дело.

Comment: @Nektoid У меня звучит, но это не есть хорошо. Разговорный хак с кучей коннотаций (у меня), что что-то не в порядке. Пример Акунина туда же. Тире лучше поставить, а то "это" ссылается на нечто, сказанное ранее, как вы и говорили. Чтобы ликвидировать двусмысленность. *Совсем другое дело* — тогда структура не нарушена: *Плохо — это тогда, когда идёт дождь.*

Comment: @Nektoid *лишнее нагромождение* — ну да, просто показываю, что структура корректна. Но здесь не условие определяется, а предикатив. Предлагаете "то" вообще не использовать? Оно ж на смысл не оказывает влияния.

Comment: @oleed [я переписал сообщение, но оно с телефона почему-то не отправилось, только сейчас это заметил.] Лично я "то" как часть двойного союза использую редко и в целях скорее стилистических. Пример: "Я подумал, что если будет холодно, сыро, темно, то будет всем жителям конец". Уберите здесь "то" — и финальная "будет" приклеится к предыдущему перечислению, а читатель наверняка запнётся. Конечно, в данном случае второе "будет" лучше заменить на "станет", но это просто пример. (В идеале и от "что" стоит избавиться: "Я подумал: если будет холодно, сыро, темно — всем жителям конец".)

Comment: @Nektoid Это разграничитель. Когда-то без него лучше, а когда-то — хуже. С особенностями употребления долго и сложно разбираться. Там может быть очень много нюансов. Мне больше с ним нравится, чем без него. Лично я против подхода "чем меньше слов, тем лучше" — другое дело, если меньше воды, — но это актуально для программирования. Слова формируют звучание. Это как узор. Система учитывает также удалённые сообщения (тупой принцип), перед тем как вызвать модератора, чтобы он удалил их в чат. А эти чаты после некоторого времени неактивности тоже удаляются. То есть надо поменьше удалять.

Comment: @oleed Узор бывает разным. Кому-то милы бантики и рюшечки барочной музыки, кому-то гигантизм Вагнера, кому-то медитативный минимализм тен Хольта. Я из последних, поэтому и в литературе исповедую принцип "писать надо так, чтобы словам было тесно, а мыслям просторно". Вот, кстати, стиль Акунина мне нравится: ёмкий, но внешне несложный, "подсушенный". Только тропов, как по мне, маловато, но это вкусовщина.

Comment: @Nektoid В этом узоре заключается стиль речи человека. Например, отсутствие "то" будет выделять его среди остальных. А кому-то просто всё то, что очень красиво, как мне. Прикольный принцип, парадоксальный. В чём смысл? Чтоб быстрее изложить/прочитать? Чтоб меньше бумаги ушло (беречь деревья)? Чем короче, тем проще понять?

Comment: @oleedd это не про "короче". Минималистические оперы Гласса не короче фундаментальных опер Вагнера. И уж точно не про "проще". Смысл в разглаживании обёртки ради обострения сути. Разница потенциалов создаёт уникальный и, понятно, не всем интересный художественный эффект. Поднимает текст до притчи. Сравните творчество Л. Толстого и Чехова: молотьба дубиной и работа стилетом. И то и другое может быть смертельно, то есть достигнуть эффекта, но как по мне, так второе — оно красивее.

Comment: @Nektoid Я не про музыку, а про текст. Про минимальное количество слов. В музыке другое. Ну да, в движениях со шпагой грация. То же с катаной.

Comment: @oleedd так "необходимый минимум" — это и про музыку, и про текст, и про боевые искусства, нацеленные на эффективность, а не внешний эффект. И даже про изобретательство... Одно из главных правил ТРИЗа: "лучшая деталь — та, которой нет, но её функции выполняются". Замените "деталь" на "слово" — и увидите, как этот принцип изобретательства я обратил в один из своих принципов стилистики.

Comment: @Nektoid Шесть роялей у тен Хольта — это минимум? Меньше слов — короче текст. А в музыке длина не сокращается, у тен Хольта фортепианное произведение на полтора часа. Так что отличия есть. В музыке оно так не работает — минимальность может быть разве что в одноголосии, — там просто используются особые средства выразительности. Потому что текст — как 2D, а музыка — как 3D (потому что голоса там как слои), она при упрощении становится плоской. Эффективность — да, но краткость — не основной залог эффективности. Но связь имеется: краткое проще понять; быстрее алгоритмы выполняются.

Comment: @oleedd вещи тен Хольта можно играть и на одном рояле, у него не прописан состав. Но суть не в этом. Текст тоже может быть многослоен, другое дело, что слои в нём приходится располагать последовательно (даже в таких экспериментально-полифоничных вещах, как "Хазарский словарь"). Принцип "меньше слов" не значит "меньше, чем было бы, если бы..." Это изначально не категория для сравнения. Это художественный приём. "Роман Е. Водолазкина 'Лавр' написан в стилистике 'меньше слов'" — так можно сказать. "Роман Е. Водолазкина 'Лавр' был бы на 30% толще, если бы..." — так нельзя.

Comment: @Nektoid Не похоже, что они играют в унисон. Слои — это когда одновременно, а не последовательно. А дальше не понял. Честно говоря, я большой фанат этого принципа в том, где есть количество шагов (например, решение головоломки). Но это не про искусство. И к искусству это меньше всего применимо.

Comment: @oleedd к искусство может быть применимо всё)
Что касается слоёв, то любое искусство, что разворачивается во времени, у вас в голове "перестраивается" в пространство. Отсюда и термин "композиция" по отношению к тексту: взаиморасположение элементов в готовом "здании". Самый простой пример: если текст описывает события, происходящие в одно время в разных местах, это выглядит как одна глава про одно событие, потом другая — про другое. Но вы в голове совершенно без проблем соединяете две последовательно прочитанные главы в единое двуслойное строение.

Comment: @oleedd (что касается композиторской техники тен Хольта, то это отдельная тема, разъяснить которую затруднительно в формате комментариев из-за ограничений в знаках и объёме темы.)

Comment: @Nektoid Это да, но это о восприятии. А у меня речь о структуре. Музыка состоит из слоёв в плане структуры. Есть стили, которые распространяются на разные виды искусства. Но визуальные виды искусства и музыкальное очень отличаются, поэтому многие вещи не могут перейти из одного в другое. Поэтому минимализм, например, в живописи и минимализм в музыке — это разные вещи.

Comment: @oleedd я, кстати, экспериментировал со слоями в тексте. Буквально: некоторые предложения писал "в два этажа", начало и конец были объединены строкой, а то, что между ними, представляло собой две строки с похожим, но разнящимся текстом. (Схематично: -==-, где дефисы — общие начало и конец, а между ними две различающиеся строки.) При чтении беглым взглядом возникало весьма любопытное шизофреническое ощущение, потому что оба слоя воспринимались одновременно, но из-за их неполной тождественности срабатывал какой-то психостереоэффект. Но это всё-таки баловство, неприменимо на постоянку.

Comment: @Nektoid Ну а как читать две строки одновременно? Как произносить одновременно? Так не получится. Тем более что вторую строку нужно прочитать после первой, чтоб понять смысл. Иначе информация должна быть независимой. Можно смотреть на две строчки одновременно, как на два нотных стана при игре на фортепиано, но смысла в этом нет.

Comment: @oleedd зачем произносить? Понятно, что это приём для глаз, а не аудиокниг (хотя и там возможно сделать двойную начитку и развести по каналам). Не то время сейчас, чтобы ориентироваться на звучание. И потому, кстати, особого смысла нет в строгой стилистике наподобие "никаких зияний и кластеров, два слова подряд не должны начинаться с гласной..." и проч. Что касается чтения сразу с двух строк, то в этом и была фишка.

Comment: @Nektoid Читать без произношения сложно. Но проблема даже не в этом, а в том, что вторая строка — это продолжение первой. А читать два разных текста одновременно как-то бредово, как и слушать их по разным каналам. Многослойности в этом нет, потому что такие слои не соотносятся, они не дополняют друг друга, как в музыке. Но подобное встречается, например, в фильмах: когда люди говорят одновременно о каком-то событии, их голоса накладываются, но тогда трудно всё понять.